# How to use modal box using javascript and asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Basically i tried creating a modal box that will appear after clicking a button for submission. It will either display upload successful or upload failed. Now, I have two problems that i have encountered that i am hoping that you guys can help me out. Here are the questions:

1. After clicking the submit button, it will appear roughly for 3 seconds and then it will postback. After that, the modal box is gone. What i want to happen is, the modal box should not disappear unless i clicked the x button. Then after that, the webpage can now do postback. If possible, how to achieve this?
2. Also, i have noticed that the modal box that i have integrated in my website cannot distinguish if the upload is successful or fail. I can see that it will still display upload successful even if the submission is failed. As of now, I have only coded the upload successful because I don't know yet on how to apply the upload fail yet. It should be able to determine if the submit button is successful or failed. How to achieve this?

Here is the aspx and script:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" Text="Save 
     Item" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>

               <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                   <!-- Modal content -->
                   <div class="modal-content">
                      <span class="close">&times;</span>
                      <p>Upload Successful</p>
                   </div>
              </div>
     <script>

    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


    var btn = document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>');


    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }


    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }


    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code-behind. Take note, i haven't really put anything inside the catch because its suppose to return an upload failed popup box:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        int item_brandId =  
         ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByBrand(itemBrand.Text);
        string item_model = itemModel.Text;
        double item_price = Convert.ToDouble(itemPrice.Text);
        string item_image1 = Session["PicturePath1"].ToString();
        string item_image2 = Session["PicturePath2"].ToString();
        string item_description = itemDescription.Text;
        string item_necktype = itemNeckType.Text;
        string item_body = itemBody.Text;
        string item_fretboard = itemFretboard.Text;
        string item_fret = itemFret.Text;
        string item_bridge = itemBridge.Text;
        string item_neckpickup = itemNeckPickup.Text;
        string item_bridgepickup = itemBridgePickup.Text;
        string item_hardwarecolor = itemHardwareColor.Text;

        if (itemType1.Checked)
        {
            int item_type = 
            ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByType(itemType1.Text);
            ItemType = item_type;
        }
        else if (itemType2.Checked)
        {
            int item_type = 
           ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByType(itemType2.Text);
            ItemType = item_type;
        }

        var item = new instrumentItem
        {
            typeId = ItemType,
            brandId = item_brandId,
            model = item_model,
            price = item_price,
            itemimage1 = item_image1,
            itemimage2 = item_image2,
            description = item_description,
            necktype = item_necktype,
            body = item_body,
            fretboard = item_fretboard,
            fret = item_fret,
            bridge = item_bridge,
            neckpickup = item_neckpickup,
            bridgepickup = item_bridgepickup,
            hardwarecolor = item_hardwarecolor
        };

        ConnectionClassGuitarItems.AddStringInstrumentItems(item);

        ClearTextFields2();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }


}
```

Here is the stylesheet if necessary:

```
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```